# How do I manage my Ubuntu One Music Store account, specifically change my email address?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've changed email addresses and would like to update my Ubuntu One Music Store account. The receipts for purchases are going to the wrong address. I can't seem to find a place to make this change.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to https://login.ubuntu.com/
- Login using your email address and password.
- Click "Manage email addresses".
- Add your new email.
- After verifying your email, go back to Ubuntu Single Sign On then select your new email in "Preferred email". Click "Update".
- If it still uses your old email (it happened to me in Ubuntu One), remove the old one in "Manage email addresses".

Comment: I've done all of these steps, except for removing the old email address. It sounds like Ubuntu One Music Store isn't properly picking up and honoring a change in preferred email address in my Ubuntu single sign on account.

I don't know if Ubuntu One staff are reading this, but if so, can you speak to that and whether or not I should file bug? If I should file a bug, can you point me in the right direction for where to submit it?

Comment: Try asking in IRC (#ubuntu). I also don't know what project is related to "Ubuntu Single Sign On" in launchpad. Maybe they can tell you how. I think it is a bug.
Note that currently (because of this bug) even if the preferred email is set to be your new email, Ubuntu One and other related services may still use the old one (which what happened to me). Removing the old one will force them to use the new one. So if you haven't tried the last step, you may try doing that.

Comment: I've now tried the last step. That did not work either. It continues to send receipts to my old email address.